# How to disable minimize and maximize button in anchor_popup()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I need to have a popup window. I used the anchor_popup function. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$attributes = array(
    'class'     =>  'blue-button',
    'width'     =>  '800',
    'height'    =>  '600',
'resizable' => 'no',
    'screenx'   =>  '\'+((parseInt(screen.width) - 800)/2)+\'',
    'screeny'   =>  '\'+((parseInt(screen.height) - 600)/2)+\'',
);
echo anchor_popup('admin/employee/add', 'Start Worksheet', $attributes);
?>
```

This opens a new window with the close, minimize, and maximize buttons But I need to disable or hide the minimize and maximize buttons. How can I do this?

Comment: i don't think codeigniter had written it to do that, i might be wrong but just saying. I recommend either hand coding it with jquery or using jquery to do that for you.

Comment: can you give me some code?

Comment: go into google and type : "How can i hide the minimize maximum buttons on a popup using jquery"

Comment: Is it possible only with jquery?

Comment: yes, jquery or javascript, which ever is your preference. Or you can write your own helper library to perform what you need. either case it'll work.